# calling same function with different types in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

> I have a list of dictionaries where I am traversing them on by one.
>   eg.

```
def same_func(messages):
    for message in messages:
        #message is a dict here.
```

> Now I also want to call this function in a different scenario where my
>   messages is a list of tuples (dict and flag)

so suppose I have made this list like -

```
messages.append((message, flag))
```

and now I want to call the same function like same_func(messages)
Then how can I make the same_func generic for both scenarios.

Comment: You can modify your logic on basis of isinstance. Like -> 
 if isinstance(messages,tuple):.. 
 elif...

Answer (score 0):

why not add a if statement in your for loop that determines the type and then handles the dict or tuple based of that.

i.e.:

```
def same_func(messages):
    for message in messages:
        if type(message) is dict:
            # handle dict
        elif type(message) is tuple:
            # handle tuple
        else: 
            # do something else
```